# Counting the number of unique formulas in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a big workbook with 50+ worksheets and I would like to count the number of unique formulas in the workbook. I used the inbuilt to find option to find '=' but this returns duplicate formulas due the drag option in excel. Any ideas would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sliiightly different answer than you may be expecting, but if you go to the FORMULAS ribbon, -->Formula Auditing section --->Show Formulas, it will change all cells so that they display what's actually in the formula bar, instead of what the simplification of that formula is.

Using this is often the simplest way to check for what formulas are actually present in a workbook.

As for counting the 'unique' formulas you are using, that's possible, but could you clarify why you want it? What will you be using that information for? If you explain your needs a little more clearly someone could likely provide a more useful solution.

Comment: Also, define "UNIQUE" formula. ie: is "=A1+B1" the same in your mind as "="B1+B2?" Or are you looking to see which FUNCTIONS are being used? Like, you want to know that somewhere uses VLOOKUP, and somewhere uses SUMIFS, etc.

Comment: thanks for the help. I would like to know how many formulas I have so as to make a rough estimate as to how many lines of equivalent lines of mathematica code I would need if I were to rewrite all the formulas. In my case A1+ B1 is similar to B1+B2.